# Microsoft as external provider with Individual Authentication failed login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core project with NET7, I followed the instructions from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

### Create the app in Microsoft Developer Portal

- Add the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount/) NuGet package to the project.
- Navigate to the [Azure portal - App registrations](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908) page and create or sign into a Microsoft account:

In the **App registrations** page:

- Select **New registration**
- Enter a **Name**.
- Select an option for **Supported account types**.

  - I selected **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**
- Under **Redirect URI**: https://localhost:7094/signin-microsoft

[image]

#### Create client secret

- In the left pane, select **Certificates & secrets**.
- Under **Client secrets**, select **New client secret**

  - Add a description for the client secret.
  - Select the **Add** button.
- Under **Client secrets**, copy the value of the client secret.

[image]

In the *appconfig.json* I added the client id and client secret and then added in the *Program.cs* the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
    });

// Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
    {
        microsoftOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
        microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
    });
```

In the login page, I can see a button for Microsoft and I can sign in the the Microsoft website. It asks me to authorize the application and I click on *Accept*

Then, the application redirects me to the local address but I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: invalid_client;Description=AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app '74160336-06b3-4a43-9f48-e0925b6d8ac5'.
> Trace ID: 22ef0073-ff34-49e2-bb60-851a495a6200
> Correlation ID: a1ce6936-eb71-4016-92c4-6ea54b64f949
> Timestamp: 2023-09-21 23:07:40Z;Uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215
> Unknown location
>
> Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

[image]

Comment: According to that error message, it ask you to ensure you have used the right client secret. I suggest you could re-generate a new client secret and client id and test again.

Comment: Hi Enrico, I found one of your image has contained your own Email, I have helped you delete it and please commit it next time. Thanks